# Opengl Texture Repeating

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to put this smiley face on the screen with opengl but the texture kinda repeating and messed up
here's the code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stb_image.h>
#include "include/Shader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdexcept>

void ercb(int err, const char* d)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", d);
}

void fbfcb(GLFWwindow* w, int t, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, t, h);
}

void glfwProcessInput(GLFWwindow* w)
{
    if(glfwGetKey(w, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(w, true);
    }
}

float vertices[] = {
    // positions          // colors           // texture coords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    // top left
};
unsigned int indices[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
    0, 1, 3,   // first triangle
    1, 2, 3    // second triangle
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    glfwInit();
    glfwSetErrorCallback(ercb);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* w = glfwCreateWindow(1080, 720, "OpenGL works!", NULL, NULL);
    if(!w)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create a window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        _Exit(1);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(w);


    if(!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        _Exit(1);
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(w, fbfcb);

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    Shader shader("shaders/vertexshader.glsl", "shaders/fragmentshader.glsl");


    unsigned int VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned int texture;

    int width, height, nrChannels;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);

    if(data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);


    unsigned int EBO;


    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8  * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8  * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8  * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


    glUseProgram(shader.ID);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "texture"), 0);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(w))
    {
        glfwProcessInput(w);

        glClearColor(0.f, 0.5f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);


        shader.use();


        //Scware :OO
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(w);
    }


    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);



    glfwTerminate();
    system("pause");
}
```

I also have this Shader class to load the shaders, because i dont want to load the shaders myself:

```
#ifndef SHADER_H_INCLUDED
#define SHADER_H_INCLUDED

#include <glad/glad.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode   = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure& e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessary
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use()
    {
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
    {
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec4(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z, w);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec3(const std::string &name, float x, float y, float z)
    {
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec2(const std::string &name, float x, float y)
    {
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y);
    }

private:
    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(unsigned int shader, std::string type)
    {
        int success;
        char infoLog[1024];
        if (type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

#endif // SHADER_H_INCLUDED
```

I expected it to just output the face in a box but the result is this:
[image]

here's the original image:
[image]

here's the code for the fragment and vertex shader:

```
vertex:


#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;   // the position variable has attribute position 0
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor; // the color variable has attribute position 1
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
  
out vec3 ourColor; // output a color to the fragment shader
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}  


fragment:


#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor; 
 
in vec3 color;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture;
  
void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture, TexCoord);
    
    //colored texture
    //FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0) * texture(texture, TexCoord);
}
```

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the rows of your image are not 4-byte aligned, as expected by default by OpenGL's pixel unpack operations, like `glTexImage2D`.

Your image has a pixel width of 299 pixels and has 3 components, so every line has a byte-length of 299*3 = 897, which is not a multiple of 4.

There are a two ways to fix this:

1. set the pixel unpack alignment to `1` byte by calling: `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` before calling `glTexImage2D()`
2. tell stb_image to explicitly expand your image to have `4` components (alpha will be `1.0` in this case), by specifying a `4` instead of your `0` as the last argument to `stbi_load(..., 4);` and then use `GL_RGBA8` and `GL_RGBA` as the internalFormat and format arguments to `glTexImage2D()`